# Creating Add-on libraries for SDK in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I want to create an add-on library for an SDK. Is it any different from importing the required header files from the main SDK in my new add-on library and creating a static library from that? Is there something I'm missing?

Update:
I want an addon like JJAFAcceleratedDownloadRequestOperation for AFNetworking.

Comment: You just need your library to link against the other library or libraries it depends on.

Comment: @jlehr Are there any tutorial I could refer to on how to do that?

Comment: All that's required is clicking a button in Xcode -- not sure why you'd need a tutorial for that. If you're new to Xcode, Apple's documentation would be a great place to start, for example: [Linking to a Library or Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)

Comment: @jlehr My main project has a 3rd party SDK added as a subproject. I created the add-on and added to my main project as a subproject. Now I want my add-on to reference my SDK subproject so I could use methods from it. How can his be done? I tried adding my libSDK.a file in my add-on target's Link Binary With Libraries, but I got duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 error when I try to compile.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. But...
You can make reflexion on it.

Your add-on have to be autonomous and in your main SDK, you make reflexion to test if the add-on is integrated. If there is added, you can call him.